# Mysql получить отсутствующие занчения

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT id, NickName, Tel  
FROM clients 
WHERE id IN (" + client_ids + ");
```

Получаю список клиентов которые есть в базе, но мне нужно так же получить и id тех которые отсутствуют в базе.
Переменная `client_ids` со списком клиентов приходит из другой базы.
Требуется получить таблицу типа:

| id | NickName | Tel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Highlander | 797886952 |
| 3 | *null* | *null* |
| 40 | Sadiely | 797886952 |

`id=3` нет в базе

Придумал только по каждому запросу обращаться в базу и заполнять построчно ответами, а если 1000 клиентов, как то не очень красиво получается.

Comment: если в базе нет id их нельзя получить))

Comment: Подсказка: разница между client_ids  и теми, кто есть в БД - получаем тех, кого в БД нет

Comment: ну хотя бы null получить

Comment: Приведи ожидаемый результат

Comment: `'1', 'Highlander', '79788695231'`

Comment: в вопрос добавь.....так ничего не ясно....напиши строчки 4

Comment: `'3', null, null`

Comment: `'40', 'Sadiely', "+797883343''`

Comment: id = 3 нет в базе и хочу что бы по нему была сорока для отображения в таблице, что бы клиента можно было удалить

Comment: *Переменная client_ids со списком клиентов приходит из другой базы.* Как она выглядит **ТОЧНО**.

Comment: *Получаю список клиентов которые есть в базе, но мне нужно так же получить и id тех которые отсутствуют в базе.* Список, пригодный для отбора во WHERE/HAVING, следует преобразовать в набор записей - только тогда появится возможность выборки этих данных.

Comment: Вообще есть множество способов решить это на клиенте, там где вы формируете этот sql запрос. Вы можете например перед выполнением запроса заготовить массив под ответы, где проставить пустные значения в связке со всеми запрашиваемыми id. после чего выполнить запрос, заполнить данные в этом массиве тем, что вернула БД. В итоге у вас будет массив со всеми id и пустотами, можно использовать его для вывода таблицы.

Comment: Но если очень сильно хочется, то тогда вместо IN вам надо в from указать подзапрос вида (select id1 union all select id2 ...) и выполнить left join таблицы к этому подзапросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как один из вариантов: из переменной `client_ids` создать строку вида

```sql
SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 40 AS id
```

Где вместо *1*, *3*, *40* должны быть значения `client_ids`.

Затем эту строку можно подставить в запрос следующим видом:

```sql
SELECT id, NickName, Tel
FROM
  clients

  RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 40 AS id)
    AS ids
    USING (id)
```

В таком случае будет получена таблица-пример из вопроса.

Comment: Отлично, большое спасибо @7-zete-7

Comment: @Highlander главное чтобы client_ids потом не было случайно около 1000 штук :D

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Да это интересно, есть ли ограничение по длине у mysql запроса ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, 1000 — ещё нормально. На, около, 5000 появляются нюансы. Если изменение подхода к обработке данных остаётся под таким же табу, как и при переборе пары элементов, — придётся добавлять временную таблицу и заполнять её частями, затем уже делать простой `JOIN` на временную таблицу.